# DateTime formatting error?

Tags: c#

I want to compare dates. One date will be hard coded other will be picked from system.

My code is giving formatting error in this line:

```
string iStringdate = "05-05-2015";
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iStringdate, "dd-mm-yyyy", null);
```

**Complete code:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string iStringdate = "05-05-2015";
    DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iStringdate, "dd-mm-yyyy", null);
    //MessageBox.Show(oDate.ToString());

    string iStringtime = "10:12 pm";
    DateTime oTime = DateTime.ParseExact(iStringtime, "HH:mm tt", null);
    //MessageBox.Show(oTime.ToString());

    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

    if (oDate < date)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("successfull");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("fail");
    }

}
```

Also how can I just get the system date and not the system time along with it?

Where am I wrong?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"mm"** stands for minutes while **"MM"** means months.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(iStringdate, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

Click **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** for a complete list of date formatting options.

And `DateTime.Now` returns the date **and** time, while `DateTime.Today` returns the current date and **00:00:00** as time.

Comment: When I do MessageBox.Show(oDate.ToString()); it gives me date along with 00:00:00. how can i just get the date out of it.?

Comment: You can use the same format to convert to a string: `.ToString("dd-MM-yyy")`